# Problems with simple differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

At first: I am new to differential equations, so this question might seam a little bit obvious.

The differential eqation was $y'x^3 = 2y -5$.
I rearranged it to: $\frac{dx^3}{dx} = \frac{d(2y-5)}{dy}$.

The Problem is, if i derive it, there is no y left: $3x^2 = 2$, so how do I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint. Separate variables, i.e. $\frac{dy}{2y-5}=\frac{dx}{x^3}$ and INTEGRATE!

Comment: didn't think it was THAT easy. Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODE is linear
$$y'-2\frac{y}{x^3}=\frac{-5}{x^3}.$$
its integrating factor is $I=\exp[\int \frac{-2}{x^3} dx]=e^{1/x^2}.$
So its solution is $$y=e^{-1/x^3} \int e^{1/x^2}~ \frac{-5}{x^3} dx+ C e^{-1/x^2} \implies y= \frac{5}{2} e^{-1/x^2} \int e^u du+Ce^{-1/x^2}, u=\frac{1}{x^2} $$
$$\implies y=\frac{5}{2}+C e^{-1/x^2}$$

Comment: IMO easier as a separable equation.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is

$$\frac{dy}{dx}x^3=2y-5.$$

You cannot rearrange it to

$$\frac{dx^3}{dx} = \frac{d(2y-5)}{dy}$$

(why would those differentials appear at the numerators ?) but to

$$\frac{dx}{x^3} = \frac{dy}{2y-5}.$$

This integrates as

$$-\frac{1}{2x^2}=\frac12\log|2y-5|+C.$$